# i want to get calendar event detail which is update or change by user in android device

Tags: android

Here we consider that we are adding or deleting the calendar events from code. How to know if the event updates(adding/editing/deleting calendar events) done by the user on his/her device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it is entirely possible to monitor changes to the Calendar, but you could try:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { "_id" };
Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");

Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(calendars, projection, null, null, null);
```

and then use registerContentObserver (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#registerContentObserver%28android.database.ContentObserver%29) to monitor the Cursor for changes.

Let me know if that works.